# TextBox Style - Binding to width of text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a style for a textBox. I have in it a change to the textBox control template with a additional rectangle. I want the width of the rectangle to be bound to the width of the text that has been typed.

Here is the current style

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"             
                        Background="{DynamicResource White#}">

                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PART_ContentHost}" Height="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.8">
                            <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" />
                            </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

This xaml bar stretches I want it just to be as wide as the text

What do I have to put in the setter for the control template and what does the binding have to be?

Comment: Try ActualWidth.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Targetting what object. Targetting the scroll viewer captures the textBoxs width not the text I have typed?

Comment: I gave you the level of detail that's possible with the information you provided. I'm not going to play guessing games about what's in your template.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have edited the post with some more detail. Please could you consider the changes

Comment: You're not going to be able to accomplish this in just XAML as a reusable ControlTemplate. You'll need to write converters to take into consideration things like FontSize, FontFamily, CultureInfo, etcetera that I know personally I wouldn't have time to go figure out for free. However, if this is something that is say a small usage thing where for example you're just needing it for a single instance than I can show you a very quick workaround in pure xaml to accomplish your goal which if you wanted you could turn into say a ContentControl for re-use. I stress QUICK WORKAROUND though.

Comment: @BenWebb See update for complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Ed's is better. I didn't even think about just handling focus and letting the ActualWidth of the ScrollViewer provide the value. I was thinking more immersed of actually measuring Text Element within the ScrollViewer as a logical child element which would have been much more involved in my opinion. Except his way works. However I also ran into an issue awhile back where by strict requirements only XAML was allowed with no codebehind to accomplish the same thing. Except it was a single instance form input and this quick hack was allowed.

I'd go with Ed's personally but submitted just as a quick alternative you can do something like this, and just piggy back the values to get ActualWidth off another element. It's not elegant, but it is simple...

[image]

PoC xaml;

```
Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="theText" 
                       Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=theBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBox   x:Name="theBox" 
                       Height="30" Width="250" MaxLength="50"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Green" 
                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=theText}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25"/>
    </Grid>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You were very close.

First, I added `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` to the `ScrollViewer`, to prevent it from stretching to the full width of its parent.

Second, I removed the `ScaleTransform` that shrank the Rectangle to a horizontal size of zero.

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ScrollViewer 
        Margin="0" 
        x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        />
    <Rectangle 
        x:Name="Rect1" 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PART_ContentHost}" 
        Height="2" 
        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.8"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        >
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Now you've got another problem: The user has to click inside the `ScrollViewer` to make it get focus so he can start typing, and the scrollviewer is a little thing crowded into the left hand side of the control. I'm looking at some ways to do that; stand by for an update.

### Update

How to handle focus on mousedown without committing any sins against MVVM:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyRandomNamespace
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        #region Extensions.MouseDownFocusRecipient Attached Property

        //  Attached property. See XAML example below for usage. 
        //  On mouse down, sets focus on bound target control. 

        public static UIElement GetMouseDownFocusRecipient(UIElement obj)
        {
            return (UIElement)obj.GetValue(MouseDownFocusRecipientProperty);
        }

        public static void SetMouseDownFocusRecipient(UIElement obj, UIElement value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(MouseDownFocusRecipientProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDownFocusRecipientProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseDownFocusRecipient", typeof(UIElement), typeof(Extensions),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, MouseDownFocusRecipient_PropertyChanged));

        private static void MouseDownFocusRecipient_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var target = d as UIElement;

            //  Target must have some kind of background color or it will ignore mouse events. 
            //  We can't do this object-orientedly because multiple Background dependency 
            //  properties are defined in multiple control classes. 

            var bkgDepProp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName("Background", target.GetType(), target.GetType(), true);

            if (bkgDepProp != null && bkgDepProp.GetValue(target) == null)
            {
                bkgDepProp.SetValue(target, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent);
            }

            //target.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            target.PreviewMouseDown -= Target_PreviewMouseDown;
            target.PreviewMouseDown += Target_PreviewMouseDown;
        }

        private static void Target_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var target = (UIElement)sender;

            var otherControl = GetMouseDownFocusRecipient(target);

            if (otherControl != null)
            {
                Keyboard.Focus(otherControl);
            }
        }
        #endregion Extensions.MouseDownFocusRecipient Attached Property
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <Border 
        Name="Border"
        Padding="2"             
        Background="{DynamicResource White#}"
        local:Extensions.MouseDownFocusRecipient="{Binding ElementName=PART_ContentHost}"
        >
        <StackPanel 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            MouseDown="StackPanel_MouseDown"
            >
            <ScrollViewer 
                Margin="0" 
                x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                />
            <Rectangle 
                x:Name="Rect1" 
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PART_ContentHost}" 
                Height="8" 
                Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Opacity="0.8"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I didn't even think of still using the scrollviewer's actualwidth and just passing off focus. +1 dude. :)